# How to update multiple column and another column of another table in python tkinter mysql

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, sql-update

I am trying to update datas of a table, but in this table I am using a foreign key.
I need to be able to update the data of the foreign key if needed but I have this error :
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'helicopter_name' in 'field list'`

Here are my tables :

```
mycursor.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE Helicopter(\
        id_produitp INT NOT NULL,\
        id_helicopter INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,\
        helicopter_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,\
        helicopter_surface_mouille INT(5) NOT NULL,\
        CONSTRAINT helicopter_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY(id_produitp)\
            REFERENCES ProduitP(id_produitp)\
        )"
)

mycursor.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE New_Helicop(\
        id_helicopter INT NOT NULL,\
        id_new_helicop INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,\
        new_helicopter_start_date DATE NOT NULL,\
        new_helicopter_end_date DATE NOT NULL,\
        new_helicopter_number_peaple FLOAT NOT NULL,\
        CONSTRAINT new_helicop_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY(id_helicopter)\
            REFERENCES Helicopter(id_helicopter)\
        )"
)
```

And here is my update function with my sql query :

```
def update_record(self):
        self.selected = self.my_tree.focus()
        self.my_tree.item(self.selected, text="", values=(self.id_entry.get(), self.programme_entry.get(), self.start_date_entry.get(), self.end_date_entry.get(), self.number_peaple_entry.get(),))

        id = self.id_entry.get()
        programme = self.programme_entry.get()
        start_date = self.start_date_entry.get()
        end_date =  self.end_date_entry.get()
        effectif = self.number_peaple_entry.get()

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host = "localhost",
                user = "blabla",
                password = "blabla",
                auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
                database = "blabla"
            )
        cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered = True)
        
        sql = ("UPDATE New_Helicop \
                SET helicopter_name= %s, new_helicopter_start_date= %s, new_helicopter_end_date= %s, new_helicopter_number_peaple= %s \
                WHERE id_new_helicop= %s")
        values = (programme, start_date, end_date, effectif, id)
        cursor.execute(sql, values)

        mydb.commit()

        self.id_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.programme_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.start_date_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.end_date_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.number_peaple_entry.delete(0, END)
```

Just to add more info about what is want to do, i done a treeview, and when i clicked on a row, i catch datas of this row on Entry's and if i want, i can delete those entry's, or update it.

Comment: The error obviously tells you that `helicopter_name` is not a field inside `New_Helicop` table.

Comment: @acw1668 yes I know, but to explain, when i clicked, I recover datas in entry's, and after that i want to modify those datas.
But ```helicopter_name``` is not in the ```New_Helicop``` table as you said. But in this table i have a foreign key, and thx to this i want to modify this data. So i dont know how to do this in this query

Comment: Simply update the two tables in two UPDATE SQL statements.

Comment: I dont want to update the Helicopter Table, i just want to update the helicopter_name data in my view, from the New_Helicop table thx to my foreign key column